# Why do I need for loop to get all of the element of this array list, why can't I use Int range of the Intrange like in loop?

Tags: kotlin

I want to print all of the gun that I have indexed using 'gunIndex' variable. I could use loop for this, but why can't I do this without a loop? When using for loop, why can I print IntRange despite it wasn't Int type? `gun[gunIndex]` This is the error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is IntRange but Int was expected

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var gun = arrayListOf<String>("ak47", "m249 SAW", "Dessert Eagle")
    gun.add("AKM")
    gun.add("AK74")
    var nomerGun = 0

    var gunIndex = 0..gun.size-1

    println(gun[gunIndex])
}
```

Why when using for loop I don't get this error?

> Type mismatch: inferred type is IntRange but Int was expected

When I print it?

I can't understand why I can't do it without loop, and why for loop can print `gun[gunIndex]` despite `[gunIndex]` operator is filled with `IntRange`.

Comment: You haven't shown your for loop, but in the for loop, `gunIndex` is (probably) an `Int`, not a `IntRange`. That is a fundamental and important difference. However, you should be able to use `gunIndex.forEach { println(gun[it]) }`, but then why not just do `gun.forEach` as suggested by Tobias...

Comment: Every time I see any code or information posted here that came from ChatGPT, there's something fundamentally wrong with it or it has numerous subtle errors and bad practices in the code. I think trying to learn from ChatGPT is more harmful than not, and it's wasting your time. It's not sophisticated enough for this yet. Stick to tutorials and official documentation. It's not going to be able to answer a question that hasn't been asked numerous times on the web with good answers, and if your question has been asked a lot before, you can find it on this site.

Comment: Yes, I need to repeat what Tenfour04 says: don't rely on ChatGPT. It is nothing more than a dumb bullshit generator, which might come across convincing, but it is more than likely telling you something that is wrong or incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if want to do something with all elements of a Collection you have have do *some* kind of looping. Can be a classical for/foreach-loop, iterator and while loop, etc.

How does your for-loop looks like?

If you want print all items in a simple oneliner use:

```
gun.forEach { println(it) }
```

Comment: im past this basic usage. so thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

This declares `gunIndex` to be of `IntRange` type (i.e., a list of Ints):

```
var gunIndex = 0..gun.size-1
```

Indexing into an array requires an `Int` to indicate which specific index to retrieve the value at. Trying to index into an array using a range of values makes no logical sense, hence the error.

```
println(gun[gunIndex]) // which one of the "gun" items is supposed to be printed if gunIndex is the range of all of them?
```

> when using for loop why i can print IntRange despite it wasnt Int type?

You didn't show code so I have to assume you are misunderstanding. You probably have something like:

```
for (gunIndex in 0..gun.size-1) {
    println(gun[gunIndex])
}
```

Which makes `gunIndex` an `Int` for each iteration of the loop, which can be used to index into the array.

Comment: so i must  define which gun i want  to print trhough specified indeks variable ? that solved the problem.

im tryng to create a code which when i input a number, it will show the name of the gun based of index using for loop. but it looks like i cant do that.it must pre defined on each variabel

Comment: @getchwaltzetki if you're looking up an item based on a specific index you don't need a `for` loop, you just access it directly with `gun[index]`. A for loop is just repeating something over a set of items / range of numbers etc